# Shared map with boost::interprocess

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I have a simple requirement that might be tough to solve. I did find some leads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503834/boost-interprocess-map-with-int-and-string) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842082/map-in-shared-memory) but I can't seem to readilly use them. The former doesn't even translate into buildable code for me. I am not experienced with Boost to just write this on my own but it seems to me this might be a common requirement.

I have also come across [Interprocess STL Map](http://www.crystalclearsoftware.com/cgi-bin/boost_wiki/wiki.pl?Interprocess_STL_Map) but I have not yet been able to assemble it into working code.

I am thinking `boost::interprocess` is the way to go here, unless I want to create some shared memory map from scratch.

I am not concerned with portability. I need a solution that will work with MS compiler, specifically the one that comes with VS 2010.

[This poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503834/boost-interprocess-map-with-int-and-string) seems to want to more or less what I am trying to do, except I need to map a GUID to an arbitrary length binary buffer (but an int to string is equally good as a starting point). Unfortunately, I cannot compile the code cleanly to even begin with experiments.

Also I have two concerns: A) is it possible to automatically (or at least predictably) grow/shrink the shared memory to accommodate allocation needs and B) assuming one process creates the map, how can another process "attach" to it?

I don't mind if a solution requires multiple shared "segments" in order to satisfy allocation needs. It doesn't necessarily have to be a single monolithic shared chunk of memory.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, `boost::interprocess::map` should give you just what you need.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's recent example which i had written to learn the usage of maps in Shared memory. It compiles so probably, you can experiment with it to suit your requirement.

The code for a server process which creates Shared memory and puts map into it:-

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

int main ()
{
    using namespace boost::interprocess;

    // remove earlier existing SHM
    shared_memory_object::remove("SharedMemoryName");

    // create new 
    managed_shared_memory segment(create_only,"SharedMemoryName",65536);

    //Note that map<Key, MappedType>'s value_type is std::pair<const Key, MappedType>,
    //so the allocator must allocate that pair.
    typedef int    KeyType;
    typedef float  MappedType;
    typedef std::pair<const int, float> ValueType;

    //allocator of for the map.
    typedef allocator<ValueType, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;

    //third parameter argument is the ordering function is used to compare the keys.
    typedef map<KeyType, MappedType, std::less<KeyType>, ShmemAllocator> MySHMMap;

    //Initialize the shared memory STL-compatible allocator
    ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());

    // offset ptr within SHM for map 
    offset_ptr<MySHMMap> m_pmap = segment.construct<MySHMMap>("MySHMMapName")(std::less<int>(), alloc_inst);

    //Insert data in the map
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
            m_pmap->insert(std::pair<const int, float>(i, (float)i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code for a client process which attaches to the memory and accesses map's data.

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/map.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    using namespace boost::interprocess;

    try
    {

            managed_shared_memory segment(open_or_create, "SharedMemoryName",65536);

            //Again the map<Key, MappedType>'s value_type is std::pair<const Key, MappedType>, so the allocator must allocate that pair.
            typedef int    KeyType;
            typedef float  MappedType;
            typedef std::pair<const int, float> ValueType;

            //Assign allocator 
            typedef allocator<ValueType, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator;

            //The map
            typedef map<KeyType, MappedType, std::less<KeyType>, ShmemAllocator> MySHMMap;

            //Initialize the shared memory STL-compatible allocator
            ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
                                                                                        
            //access the map in SHM through the offset ptr                                                         
            MySHMMap :: iterator iter;
            offset_ptr<MySHMMap> m_pmap = segment.find<MySHMMap>("MySHMMapName").first;

            iter=m_pmap->begin();
            for(; iter!=m_pmap->end();iter++)
            {
                   std::cout<<"\n "<<iter->first<<" "<<iter->second;
            }
    }catch(std::exception &e)            
    {
            std::cout<<" error  " << e.what() <<std::endl;
            shared_memory_object::remove("SharedMemoryName");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Code for the Client Process explains how using "names" and an offset pointer, other processes can attach and access the Map contents created in SHM by the server process.
But, allocating size (here its '65536') while creating a new shared memory segment, i am not sure whether the size can be shrinked, though probably you can create more chunks of shared memory for expanding the SHM...

Hope it helped...

Comment: Thanks for the great sample! Hopefully somebody will make use of it. I have found my luck some time ago and it looks awfully similar to what you posted. So +1...

Comment: Seems the size of the shared memory is fixed?

Comment: You construct (in server process) two times "MySHMMapName". In client process you defined "MySHMMapNAme" <-- capital A in NAme. It is not working for me, I deleted the first construct and renamed the names. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I assume this is not lock-free, right? Locking needs to be done separately if two processes use the map?